# Printing a MultipleSeqAlignment Object

Tags: bioinformatics, biopython, sequence-alignment

I have an alignment of 3 sequences generated by `clustalx`

```
AAAACGT Alpha
AAA-CGT Beta
AAAAGGT Gamma
```

I can sliced the alignment with the predefined indexing in Biopython via `align[:,:4]`

However, printing the result gives:

```
AAAA Alpha
AAA- Beta
AAAA Gamma
```

How can I capture sub-alignment as without printing the names as given below?

```
AAAA
AAA-
AAAA
```

`align[:,:4].seq` does not provide the output I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I need to ask a follow-up question first - what is the exact type of `align[:,:4]`?

Either way, it seems to be an array of some sort, so you cannot simply do `.seq`. What you may be able to do, if the `seq` is indeed a property of the individual entries, is to extract them using a `map` function:

```
map(lambda el: el.seq, align[:, :4])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something like:

```
for x in align[:, :4]:
    print x.seq
```

Or do whatever you want where the print statement is.